# Running a block of code in until loop Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have a problem in writing a loop in Robot Framework for a block of code.

This code firstly check some values (Minimum and Current), then compare them, and then increase another value (Quantity) by input text. I would like this block of code to be executed UNTIL the condition that Current is greater than Minimum is fulfilled.

How should I write such kind of condition?
Thanks in advance.

```
${Minimum}= Get Table Cell  xpath=...   5   3
${Current}= Get Table Cell  xpath=...   5   4   

${status}    ${value}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    
...    Should be true    ${Current} > ${Minimum}

${quantity}=    Get Value   xpath=
...    Run Keyword If   '${status}' == 'FAIL'   
...       Input Text    xpath=${quantity+10}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I manage to do this with simple FOR loop and EXIT FOR LOOP in ELSE condition.

```
: FOR   ${i}    IN RANGE    1   999                         
    ${BoxesMinimum}=    Get Table Cell  xpath=//someid    5    3        
    ${BoxesCurrent}=    Get Table Cell  xpath=//someid    5    4                    

    ${status}   ${value}=   Run Keyword and Ignore Error    
    ...    Should be true    ${BoxesCurrent} > ${BoxesMinimum}      

    ${quantity}=    Get Value   xpath=//someid

    Run Keyword If  '${status}' == 'FAIL'   
    ...              Input Text    xpath=//someid    ${quantity+10}    
    ...    ELSE    Exit for loop
```